# Using INTO to assign to a variable in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

As a background. I am trying to assign results of a group by function to a variable. With that I wanted to do something like

```
while count > n/2
BEGIN 
UPDATE table1
set exclude_reason = ....
......
```

n being the count of records from the groupby function.

I am just trying to basically use this as a dupe check but for other cases I am running into where there are many duplicates a standard dupe check would get rid of maybe 9/10 records that are the same, however; I only want to get rid of half of those.

I looked at using INTO which seems like the most standard approach. Is this the best way to go about a problem like this.

Example data:

[image]

The group by would be groupby id,amount,price,type

From there I wanted to iterate through and update half of the results of the group by function.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would *really* help.  What group by function?  What are you trying to do?  Why are you using a `while` loop instead of a set-based operation?

Comment: Added above....

Comment: Please don't paste pictures or links to picture. Use formatted text for code and sample data.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use INTO it appears to me that you'll have to do something along the lines of

```
FOR aRow IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID, AMOUNT, PRICE, TYPE
               FROM SOME_TABLE)
LOOP
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO n
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    WHERE ID = aRow.ID AND
          AMOUNT = aRow.AMOUNT AND
          PRICE = aRow.PRICE AND
          TYPE = aRow.PRICE;

  -- do whatever you want with n here
END LOOP;
```

But I fail to understand why you'd want to do this unless there is some external requirement to use `INTO` here. You'd be better off doing

```
FOR aRow IN (SELECT ID, AMOUNT, PRICE, TYPE, COUNT(*) AS N
               FROM SOME_TABLE
               GROUP BY ID, AMOUNT, PRICE, TYPE)
LOOP
  -- do whatever you want with aRow.N here
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete half of duplicated rows you can count rows for each combination (id, amount, price, type) analytically, if there is more than one row delete these where row_number divided by count is greater than `0.5`.

You can do it in **one `merge` statement and this is the best way**. But you seem to be interested in PLSQL solution, so here is standard loop:

```
begin 
  for r in (select rowid rwd, test.*, 
                   count(1) over (partition by id, amount, price, type) cnt,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, amount, price, type order by null) rn
              from test) 
  loop
    if r.cnt > 1 and r.rn / r.cnt > .5 then 
      update test set exclude_reason = 'Duplicate' where id = r.id and rowid = r.rwd;
    end if;
  end loop; 
end;
```

And below is [bulk-processing](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall) example. It's faster, but you have to define proper type and variable at first.

```
declare 
  type tr is record (id test.id%type, rwd urowid);
  type tt is table of tr;
  vt tt;
begin 
  select id, rwd 
    bulk collect into vt
    from (select rowid rwd, id, count(1) over (partition by id, amount, price, type) cnt,
                 row_number() over (partition by id, amount, price, type order by null) rn
           from test)
    where cnt > 1 and rn / cnt > .5;

  forall i in 1..vt.count
    update test set exclude_reason = 'Duplicate' 
      where id = vt(i).id and rowid = vt(i).rwd;

end;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e5585d7557fa518caf8e1952f630e7b4)</sup>**